# Change background color of embedded Terminal in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently this is the appearance of my embedded Terminal in Android Studio, very unconfortable when reading. Can someone help me to strip out the black background around the characters?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make Foreground colours of standard output and system output of Console Colors to white.

[image]

[image]

If you are using windows machine, you can change the font colors of the PowerShell/cmd.